# Does Rails 4 have a helper method that yields "Apples, Bananas and Pears" from an array ["Apples", "Bananas", "Pears"]?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Like the title, I'm wondering if either Ruby or Rails has such a helper method?

I'm aware of Ruby's `join` method, but that doesn't take the "and" into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `to_sentence` from `ActiveSupport`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence

Comment: So hard to google for this when you don't know how the docs describe it! Thanks!